# A way to avoid many servlets

Tags: java, html, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I want to avoid having many servlets because it doesn't seem right that for each button or resource on the page there will be a special servlet for it.

What I aim for is to make different ajax requests to the same servlet, and in that servlet to be able to differentiate between them in the `doGet`, `doPost` methods.

For example:

```
function bar() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "servletName",
        success: function(data) {
            foo(data);
        }
    });
}

function baz() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "servletName",
        success: function(otherdata) {
            anotherFoo(otherdata);
        }
    });
}
```

What can I add to the request to be able to differentiate between them (with if elses or switch)?

PS: I also have an html5 request (I think) so I would like to add something to it as well to make it distinct:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("myfile", document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "rooms", false);
        xhr.send(formData);
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so obvious thing you have to do is, passing an extra parameter in get and post requests from your AJAX requests and checking the parameter inside servlet using `request.getParameter("type");` // type is what you are sending from client to detect the ajax request.

Comment: You mean something like this: `data:{ajaxid:4}` to add to the ajax? Can I do this with the `XMLHttpRequest` too?

Comment: Of course, you'll be able to send. In case of get it will be a query param. In case of post another data attribute in post payload

Comment: On the server side do you use `request.getParameter("foo")` and check if the return value isn't null?

Comment: isnt null not enough , you need to also check what foo consists of and then send proper response back.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a parameter that tells what you are doing... for example, if your servlet were accessed with /myServlet you could call /myServlet?action=foo or /myServlet?action=bar and in your servlet you look for the action parameter and branch accordingly.